# trying to work an animation using the keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my current code, i cannot seem to get the animation working with the keyboard. any help?

$(document).ready(function(){

```
 $('#c4').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.which == 81) {// 81 is the value of q
        animationkeydown(this, 'push');
    }
```

});

function animationkeydown(element, animation){

```
element = $(element);
element.on('keydown',
    function() {
        element.addClass('animated push ' + animation);        

        //waits for animation to finish before removing//

        window.setTimeout( function(){
            element.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
        }, 100);         

    });
```

}

Comment: We need to see the code for `animationClick()`!

Answer (score 2):

What is `#c4`, why are you looping through each? If it's an ID there should only be one element with it.

Regardless, you're looking at adding an `onkeydown` event (this is jQuery). Assuming you have a bunch of DOM elements with id `#c4` (which you shouldn't, instead make them classes), you'd do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#c4').on('keydown', function(e) {
        if (e.which == 81) {// 81 is the value of q
            animationClick(this, 'push');
        }
});
```

This will apply the `keydown` event to every element matching that id. On the callback, `e` contains the event so `e.which` gives you which key was pressed.

EDIT: after the comments with the code of `animationClick`, assuming that one works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#c4').on('keydown', function(e) {
        var that = this; // to mimic the way you pass the element
        var animation = "push";
        if (e.which == 81) {// 81 is the value of q
            that.addClass('animated push ' + animation); //waits for animation to finish before removing
            window.setTimeout(function() {
                that.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
            }, 100);
        }
     });
});
```

Comment: what hasn't? what broke? show us more code or we really can't help you. Be more clear about what the problem is.

Comment: add console.log lines and try debugging this. When you say doesn't work, which part fails? Does your page react at all? Are there errors in the console? Did you check to see that the jquery selector even returns anything? We need some help here if you want us to help you.

Comment: ok. i cannot figure out a way to make the animation work with the keyboard. for example, Q is the note c4. i tried using your code but it doesnt work. i already have them working with the mouse click:

Comment: $('#c4').each(function() {
        animationClick(this, 'push');
    });

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't make sense what it is you're asking. Could you post the code for `animationClick`? that might help

Comment: function animationClick(element, animation){
    element = $(element);
    element.click(
        function() {
            element.addClass('animated push ' + animation);        
            
   //waits for animation to finish before removing//
            
   window.setTimeout( function(){
                element.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
            }, 100);         
  
        });
}

Comment: hahaha ok so you should probably see that this is the important part of the code. replace `element.click` with `element.on('keydown', function...)` just like I showed you on the code above. It's not the correct way of doing it so instead this is what you should do: add everything in `element.click` to the callback of the function I wrote. Then it should work.

Comment: so like this?

function animationClick(element, animation){
    element = $(element);
    element.on('keydown'
        function() {
            element.addClass('animated push ' + animation);        
            
   //waits for animation to finish before removing//
            
   window.setTimeout( function(){
                element.removeClass('animated ' + animation);
            }, 100);         
  
        });
}

Comment: but WHAT is wrong? please please tell us what goes wrong.

Comment: is there any way i can chat with you other than on the discussion?

Comment: This is a question and answer site, where you ask a specific question and the community tries to answer it. If the help here hasn't helped you, consider narrowing down your question and reposting something more coherent.

Comment: it did not trigger the animation